# How to use nditer and multi-index to index into two different arrays and build a new array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm wanting to use python/pandas/numpy to access an array (df2) (actually a pandas dataframe) to index into another array (df) based on conditional statements and build a new array (New) while appending labels.

This is a data cleaning routine I'm wanting to build for a class project I'm working on. Normally I would use Matlab for such a problem, but I don't have access now unfortunately. So far I've tried the code below that: 1) Creates a dataframe of random values called df. 2) Creates a second dataframe that is the percent increase over five rows of df1, called df2. 3) Looks at all values in df2, and from those values - using a conditional statement - creates a new dataframe called New. New consists of slices of df along with labels based on the percent change (labels are created within the loop using if statements as seen below). Also, note that the indexes defining the slices in df aren't the same as those in df2, but related by a simple shift.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10)) #Create random dataframe 
df
df2=df.pct_change(5) #Create a related dataframe df2

New=[] #Create an empty dataframe to build my new dataframe

it=np.nditer(df2, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    i=it.multi_index(0,0)
    k=it.multi_index(0,1)
    ii=i-10
    end=ii-5
    if df2.iloc[i,k]>1:
        New=df.iloc[ii:end,k].append(1, ignore_index=true)
    elif df2.iloc[i,k]>.5:
        New=df.iloc[ii:end,k].append(2, ignore_index=true)
    elif df2.iloc[i,k]>.25:
        New=df.iloc[ii:end,k].append(3, ignore_index=true)
    elif df2.iloc[i,k]>0:
        New=df.iloc[ii:end,k].append(4, ignore_index=true)
    elif df2.iloc[i,k]>-.05:
        New=df.iloc[ii:end,k].append(5, ignore_index=true)
    else:
        New=[]
    Labeled=New
    Final=Labeled.append(New, ignore_index=true)
    it.iternext()
```

I was expecting that I would get a an array called New with 6 rows and 950 columns where the 6th row is a label and rows 1 - 5 are the slice from df1. The output that I'm getting when running the code is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-7-3743c76c2bd6> in <module>()
     10 it=np.nditer(df2, flags=['multi_index'])
     11 while not it.finished:
---> 12     i=it.multi_index(0,0)
     13     k=it.multi_index(0,1)
     14     ii=i-10

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

So it's obvious that my use of multi_index isn't quite correct. My expectation after reading the nditter manual was that it.multi_index would be a 1X2 array that I could then use to relate indexes between the two dataframes and use to create slices of df. Also, I'm aware that this type of iteration isn't desirable in Python because it's slow, but I can't figure out a way to vectorize this routine since the indexes are offset and the final dataframe that is created is different than either of the input arrays. Anyhow, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at a basic multi_index, https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index

```
In [109]: it = np.nditer(np.ones(12).reshape(3,4), flags=['multi_index'])
In [110]: with it:
     ...:     while not it.finished:
     ...:         print(it.multi_index)
     ...:         it.iternext()
     ...:         
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
...
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
```

Notice that `it.multi_index` is a tuple.  That's the immediate source of your error

```
i=it.multi_index(0,0)
```

`(0,0)` is Python syntax for calling a function, not indexing (contrary to MATLAB usage).  Also `multi_index` isn't a 2d array, so `[0,0]` wouldn't be valid either.

This should get around that immediate problem:

```
 11 while not it.finished:
 12     i=it.multi_index[0]
 13     k=it.multi_index[1]
 #      i, k = it.multi_index   # using unpacking
 14     ii=i-10
```

I wonder though why you are using `nditer`.  I've never seen it applied to a dataframe.

```
In [119]: df2.shape
Out[119]: (100, 10)
In [120]: 
In [120]: it = np.nditer(df2, flags=['multi_index'])
In [121]: it.multi_index
Out[121]: (0, 0)
In [122]: it.iternext()
Out[122]: True
In [123]: it.multi_index
Out[123]: (1, 0)
In [124]: it.iternext()
Out[124]: True
In [125]: it.multi_index
Out[125]: (2, 0)
```

If I let it run to the end the last tuple will be (99,9).  So it's the same as doing

```
for i,k in np.ndindex(df2.shape):
    ....
```

But that isn't saying much because `ndindex` is one of the few places where `nditer` is used at a Python level.  `nditer` as documented in https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.nditer.html is mainly a stepping stone to using it in `cython` or other compiled code.  At a Python level it doesn't offer much, certainly not any speed.

Or equivalently:

```
for i in range(100):
    for k in range(10):
        # do stuff with i,k
```

---

Another issue

```
New=[]
```

This is a empty **list**.  We often create an array by growing a list

```
alist = []
for ....:
    alist.append(avalue)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

I'm not sure about these lines:

```
New=df.iloc[ii:end,k].append(1, ignore_index=true)
```

This assigns a new value to `New` replacing anything that was there before.  I'm not familiar with the `pandas`df[].append(...)`.  If it were the numpy`
np.append(new, x)`, I'd screaming bloody murder.

I've focused more on `numpy`, but I think there are better ways of iterating over a data frame.  `nditer` isn't a good general purpose iteration tool.  `pandas` people seem to use an `apply` quite a bit.

Comment: Okay thanks for all your input. I used the first part of what you said regarding "the immediate problem" and it seems like it may have worked.  But I can't quite tell until I get the whole thing to work. Thank you for your help so far! If another way to do a similar thing using vectorized methods occurs to you, please let me know.